# What's the fastest way in java to insert characters into a string?

Tags: java, string

I'm writing a routine that takes a string and formats it as quoted printable. And it's got to be as fast as possible. My first attempt copied characters from one stringbuffer to another encoding and line wrapping along the way. Then I thought it might be quicker to just modify the original stringbuffer rather than copy all that data which is mostly identical. Turns out the inserts are far worse than copying, the second version (with the stringbuffer inserts) was 8 times slower, which makes sense, as it must be moving a lot of memory.

What I was hoping for was some kind of gap buffer data structure so the inserts wouldn't involve physically moving all the characters in the rest of the stringbuffer.

So any suggestions about the fastest way to rip through a string inserting characters every once in a while?

Suggestions to use the standard mimeutils library are not helpful because I'm also dot escaping the string so it can be dumped out to an smtp server in one shot.

Comment: Don't use `StringBuffer`, use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I added that later, it shaved maybe 5% off the time. I'm looking for something novel that gets me orders of magnitude improvement.

Comment: I take that back, it got me 50% increase on the first version, and only 5% on the second.

Comment: (Mostly) copying to a `StringBuilder` and back to a `String` is O(2n). Exactly what orders of magnitude do you expect to lose, seeing as you can't get rid of the step of copying the data into your desired data structure?

Comment: I suggest to post your code: so people can verify any obvious mistakes, if any.

Comment: That's why I was asking you guys, see if there's some algorythmic magic I didn't know about. I heard somewhere for example there's a text search algorithm that doesn't actually have to scan every character to look for a match. Never made sense to me, but was apparently possible and faster than scanning every character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So taking the advice of some of the other answers here I've been writing many versions of this function, seeing what goes quickest and for future reference if anybody can gain from what I found:

1) The slowest: stringbuffer.append() but we knew that.

2) Almost twice as fast: stringbuilder.append(). locks are very expensive it seems.

3) another 20% faster is.... copying from one char[] to another.

4) and finally, coming in three times faster than even that... a JNI call to the exact same code compiled in C that copies from one char array to another.

You may consider #4 cheating, but cheaters win. It is by far the fastest way to go.

There is a risk of the GetCharArrayElements call causing the java char array to be copied so it can be handed to the C program, but I can't tell if that's happening, and it's still wicked fast compared to any java implementation.

Answer (score 6):

At the end, your gap data structure would have to be transformed into a String, which would need assembling all the chunks in a single array by appending them to a StringBuilder.

So using a StringBuilder directly will be faster. I don't think you'll find a faster technique than that. Make sure to initialize the StringBuilder with a large enough size to avoid copies of the whole buffer once the capacity is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good balance between speed and coding grace would be using `Matcher.appendReplacement`. Formulate a regex that will catch all insertion points. In a loop you use `find`, analyze `Matcher.group()` to see what exactly has matched, and use your program logic to decide what to give to `appendReplacement`.

In any case, it is important not to copy the text over char by char. You must copy in the largest chunks possible.

The `Matcher` API is quite unfortunately bound to the `StringBuffer`, but, as you find, that only steels the final 5% from you.